# Items automaticly size to full width of page, without defining such

Tags: html, css

I'm left to a true miracle. Or in fact: A horror. Somehow, whatever I type/define/code/create, sizes itself automatically to the full width of the page. And even if you define smaller, than somehow the div itself stretches to the full width of the page..

I've stripped it completely down to just the basics. Copied the files elsewhere and changed names so they cannot interfere with same-named ones..

Check out the screenshot, including all the code.

[image: Strange coding..]

As you can see: I've created to sets of DIV's, one with and one without a width definition. Yet, they both seem to get to the very end of the page.

Who got an idea?
Somehow the problem appears in both the editor as the browser(chrome).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The top one is narrower - so why do you believe it goes to the end of the page?

Comment: Two reasons: 1) Since the next div starts below the other one, without any break. 2) When I go into Chrome 'Inspect element' thingy, and hover over the line, it selects the whole width, instead of just the div (75px) itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block elements take up BLOCKS (=100% width even if not visibly). If you want to put something next to it, use FLOATS `float:left` or change the element to another type `display:inline-block` or `display:inline`.

What you see is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem. The `div` is a block element. It always tries to occupy 100% of the available horizontal space.

Hence the `asdfgh_nowidth` occupies 100% width while `asdfgh` occupies only 75 px.

EDIT: Take a look at this: http://codepen.io/gopkar/pen/HpAev

EDIT2: Making a `div` `float` will make it take the space of its children. Updated the pen.

Comment: Since when is this a block element? This never happened to me before. They never appear as a 'block', just normal. If it's 75px width, they are and anything can go next to it..

Comment: div's are always block elements unless specified otherwise. Take a look at the pen above.

Comment: Strange. Really never happened to me before.. How do I turn on DIV's are inline by default? Body {display:inline} - edit:This apparantly does not work, so how do I change to inline by default? ?

Comment: Yes adding display:inline; ought to do it. Or if you make it to float, it will take up the space of its contents.

Comment: Once again: This never happened to me before. I've never typed display block/inline before, yet the problem never appeared. There should be a one-time solution that helped me in the past three years..

Comment: Maybe you were `floating` all the `div`s .

Comment: I'll be going for div {float:left;} in my reset.css sheet then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default the `<div>` is a **block element** i.e with `style="display:block"` and all such `block` elements take `width=100%` i.e. 100% of the width of the container(which in this case is the page itself.).

Hence Until and unless you explicitly specify the width of the `<div>` it will by default take 100% of the width or you can simply define `style="display:inline"` to take the size of the content.